# Android 13 Photo / Video Picker - file name from the URI is garbage

Tags: android

When using the picker introduced with Android 13 via **ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia** a Uri is returned (representing the selected media item):

```
content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000198
```

If I use the content resolver and interrogate the cursor I get something like:

```
duration = 38003
orientation = 0
height = 2336
_display_name = 1000000198.mp4
datetaken = 1681826421000
mime_type = video/mp4
_data = /sdcard/.transforms/synthetic/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000198.mp4
_size = 9920806
width = 1072
```

The column usually used for the filename is *OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME* (_display_name).  However as you can tell the values here are just some garbage number filename and not the actual filename that was selected. **This is NOT the actual filename of the selected video**.

Is there any way to use this Android 13 photo/video picker and get the actual filename of the file the user selected and not this garbage number filename?

Comment: You should post your code. After that tell the obtained values.

Comment: Further it is not a garbage number name as it is equal to the last path segment of that content scheme and it will be an index in the providers database.

Comment: A different way to get the display name is `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri).getName()` But for this media picker scheme it fails too. I think that @CommonsWare has come to resque.

Comment: Even using MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE instead of column DISPLAY_NAME brings nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my personal research I don't think it's possible to get the file/display name from the Photo Picker.

This is an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268079113) (at the time of writing) and Google hasn't responded to the request yet.

The only options I see at the moment are either accepting that we don't get the filename and hoping for a fix in the future or implementing your own file/photo picker (which then of course needs extra permissions because it's not a system app)

Answer (score 0):

As far I found out, the uri the photopicker returns is a content provider uri. The content provider should give the api that satisfies your use case, without needing the actual path of the file. Feel free to read the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers

The workaround I came up with for the moment is to use the value in the `_data` column as the path. In my case I needed to access the frames. I was able to set this path as the data source of a `MediaMetadataRetriever` instance. Below is my example code (*disclaimer: I am by no means an android expert. This code may not be production ready.*).

```
    fun processUri(selectedImageUri: Uri) {
        val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
            selectedImageUri, null, null, null, null, null
        )

        if (cursor == null) {
            //...
        }
        if (cursor.count == 0) {
            //...
        }
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //...
        }

        val dataColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("_data")
        val dataPath: String = cursor.getString(dataColIndex)
        val frame = getFrame(dataPath, 0)

        state.update { _ ->
            // use frame
        }
    }

    private fun getFrame(dataPath: String, timeUs: Long): Bitmap? {
        val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        try {
            retriever.setDataSource(dataPath)
            return retriever.getFrameAtTime(timeUs, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST)
        } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
            //...
        } catch (ex: RuntimeException) {
            //...
        } finally {
            try {
                retriever.release()
            } catch (ex: RuntimeException) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
```

PS. Using the `_data` column seems like a convention baked into the api. See the [openFileHelper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/908aecc/core/java/android/content/ContentProvider.java#835) method.

Comment: Can you explain how to get the filename from the frame ? Since it was the question...

Comment: The best answer I have is looking into the content provider api documented in the link I gave. My use case did not need the actual filename, I haven't investigated it. I hope this at least gives a direction.

Comment: This also gives the same name. Not actual file name